# Usage of get in habitual action

Tags: grammar

I need to tell my son that if he hits the wall with hammer, wall will get broken.. How do I say this to my son

1. If you hit hard wall will break
2. If you hit hard wall will be broken
3. If you hit hard wall will get broken..

Which one is more appropriate in the above three sentences..

Comment: How old is your son?  Why do you need to tell him this in English?

Comment: He is 2 years old.. We are learning English...That is why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He won't understand. We don't talk to toddlers in the same way as we talk to adults.

How would the "conversation" go

> No. Don't bang the wall. Here's your blocks. See?  Let's bang the blocks. Bang Bang Bang. Can you bang the block? Can you bang? Yes! bang! No! Not the wall. If you bang the wall you'll make a hole. No! that's naughty. Give daddy the hammer. No, don't bang Daddy. Let's read a book now.....

and so on and so on, with occasional short interruptions from the toddler. The words would be supported with facial expressions, gestures, and intonation that helps the toddler understand the meaning and when you are happy or angry.

In terms of your actual sentence, the formal construction for adults would be

> If you hit the wall hard, you will break it.
>
> If you hit the wall hard, it is going to get broken.

The get passive works very well in this situation. But saying any of these to a two-year-old is going to have absolutely no effect.